# Does the ethereum ecosystem exist out of one or multiple blockchains?

Tags: blockchain

Most of my knowledge is based on BTC which doesn't have the concept of (ERC-20) 'Tokens' so I have a question related to that:

- Does the Ethereum 'ecosystem' with its hundreds or even thousands of tokens have one big Blockchain? Or does every token have its own Blockchain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the Ethereum tokens exist as smart contracts on the Ethereum blockchain. These smart contracts can be interacted with in order to transfer tokens between users. This is all part of the main Ethereum functionality, so all these tokens operate on the Ethereum blockchain.

You can take a look at how this works by looking at the specification for ERC20 tokens for instance (https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard).

Comment: Just to clarify it for me, this implies also that all erc-20 token using the same 'hash' algorithm of the ethereum blockchain because there is only one blockchain?

Comment: All token transactions are technically just Ethereum transactions, so they're all added to the same blocks as other Ethereum transactions. So they also use the same hash algorithm.